# jQuery match after regex

Tags: jquery

could someone please explain why they do not match but alert(marqueID); gives me 2 ?

```
var marqueID = marquevalue.match(/[\d-]+$/); // Contiens ID de la marque

alert(marqueID);

if (marqueID === '2'){
    alert('match');
}else{
    alert('not match')
}
```

thank you !

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead or just check the documentation for [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) (and its return value)

Comment: try using only 2 equals ( `==` ) . the `marqueID` may be int not string

Comment: What is `marquevalue`?

Comment: === used to match datatype too .

Comment: match return array so it wouldn't match data type of string  use ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match() method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

Match return array so it wouldn't match data type of string use ==

```js
marquevalue ="sdfds2";
var  marqueID = marquevalue.match(/[\d-]+$/); // Contiens ID de la marque

alert(jQuery.type(marqueID ));
alert(marqueID);

if (marqueID== '2'){
    alert('match');
}else{
    alert('not match')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```